# Java: Sort an Array Based on the Index Order of Another Array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, indexing

In Java, how can I sort an array based on the index order of another sorted array? For instance, if I have:

```
arr1 = {26, 8, 3}
arr2 = {3, 1, 2}
arr3 = {57, 23, 11}
arr4 = {78, 2, 61}
```

and I sort arr2 in ascending order to be

```
arr2 = {1, 2, 3}
```

and I want the other to then be:

```
arr1 = {8, 3, 26}
arr3 = {23, 11, 57}
arr4 = {2, 61, 78}
```

How can I accomplish this is Java? I know I would save the new sorted arrays into new instances. Anything helps, thanks!

Comment: This would be much easier if you had a single array of objects rather than four arrays of vaguely related integers.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the arrays to be separate in order to use each with different methods. You are right, though.

Comment: Why would you need them to be separate to use them for different methods? And besides, what's stopping you from bundling them into objects, performing the sort, and then unpacking them afterwards?

Comment: Store the original position of arr2, for eg. {1, 2, 0 } to track that 1 come from index 1, 2 come from index 2 and 3 come from index 0. Once you have the original position, you can sort the other arrays using the same order.

Comment: How do you sort your `arr2`?

Comment: royalghost how would I store the original position in the code? I think that may have been my original queue just in better words.  Lack of experience is what's keeping for from using other things like objects to be honest. And I haven't picked a way to sort arr2 yet. Just an easy quick way to get it in ascending order in theory. Sorry for vagueness, I'm new to this.

Comment: As long as you know how to sort one array, just do the exact same swapping code to swap other arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer elsewhere

```
public class SortTogether{

    // sort the array a, and also update the elements in array b, c, and d
    // based on the index of a
    public static void bubbleSort(int[] a, int[] b, int[] c, int[] d) {

        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<a.length-i-1;j++){
                if(a[j]>a[j+1]){
                    // when you are swapping the elements
                    int t = a[j]; a[j]=a[j+1];a[j+1]=t;
                    // swap the elements in the other arrays as well
                    // so the elements in other array will also stay together
                    t = b[j]; b[j]=b[j+1];b[j+1]=t;
                     t = c[j]; c[j]=c[j+1];c[j+1]=t;
                    t = d[j]; d[j]=d[j+1];d[j+1]=t;
                }
            }
        }

    }


    public static void main(String a[]) {
        int[] arr1 = {26, 8, 3};
        int[] arr2 = {3, 1, 2};
        int[] arr3 = {57, 23, 11};
        int[] arr4 = {78, 2, 61};
        System.out.println("Before sort");
        display(arr1);
        display(arr2);
        display(arr3);
        display(arr4);

        bubbleSort(arr2,arr1,arr3,arr4);

        System.out.println("\nAfter sort");
        display(arr1);
        display(arr2);
        display(arr3);
        display(arr4);

    }



    public static void display(int[] arr) {

        for (int num : arr) System.out.printf("%4d", num);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it.

- sort the indices of the target array based on the arrays contents.
- then use that index array to map all the arrays based on the indexed one.

```
Integer[] indices = IntStream.range(0, arr2.length)
        .boxed()                 
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(i -> arr2[i]))        
        .toArray(Integer[]::new);
                          
List<int[]> list = Stream
        .of(arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4).map(arr -> Stream
                .of(indices)
                .mapToInt(i -> arr[i])
                .toArray())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
list.forEach(arr -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)));
```

Prints

```
[8, 3, 26]
[1, 2, 3]
[23, 11, 57]
[2, 61, 78]
```

You could also place the arrays in another `"2D"` array and do as follow with the same result.

```
int[][] arrays = { arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4 };

List<int[]> list = Arrays
        .stream(arrays)
        .map(arr -> Stream
                .of(indices)
                .mapToInt(i -> arr[i])
                .toArray())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```